# errors in this basic calculator in c language

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Add(float, float);
void Subtract(float, float);
void Multiplication(float, float);
void Division(float, float);
void main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int choice;
    float num1, num2;
    printf("Welcome to the Calculator!");
    while (a == 5) {
        printf("\n1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4. Division\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (1 <= choice <= 4) {
            printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
            scanf("%f, %f", &num1, &num2);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                Add(float num1, float num2);
                break;
            case 2:
                Subtract(float num1, float num2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Multiplication(float num1, float num2);
                break;
            case 4:
                Division(float num1, float num2);
                break;
            }
            a++;
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid Input. Try again.");
    }
}
void Add(float a, float b)
{
    float ans;
    ans = a + b;
    printf("%f+%f=%f", a, b, ans);
}
void Subtract(float a, float b)
{
    float ans;
    ans = a - b;
    printf("%f-%f= %f", a, b, ans);
}
void Multiplication(float a, float b)
{
    float ans;
    ans = a * b;
    printf("%f*%f = %f", a, b, ans);
}
void Division(float a, float b)
{
    float ans, big, small;
    if (a > b) {
        ans = a / b;
        big = a;
        small = b;
    }
    else {
        ans = b / a;
        big = b;
        small = a;
        printf("%f/%f = %f", big, small, ans);
    }
}
```

There are alot of problems coming in this code, and i cant fix em, "error: expected expression before 'float'" this error is coming a lot. The problem is in coming when i make the fuction and when i call the fuction.

the problem is mainly in using the fuctions. the error is in when i give prototype of function, when i declare the function and also when i call the fuction, so its everything fuction related

Comment: Look at how you're calling `printf` and `scanf`, then look at how you're calling the functions you defined.  Notice a difference?

Comment: `Add(float num1, float num2);` should be `Add(num1, num2);`, etc. No need for the type with the argument when you are calling the function. Using `float` is not the same as performing a type cast such as `(float)`. See [C - Type Casting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).

Comment: `if (1 <= choice <= 4)` is looking suspicious. What happens is that `1 <= choice` evaluates to a `bool`, then `bool <= 4` evaluates, which is probably not what you intended. Looks like you meant `if (1 <= choice && choice <= 4)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When calling a function in C you do not need to declare the types of the arguments you are passing in.

```
Add(float num1, float num2);
```

should be

```
Add(num1, num2);
```

Make the same change for the calls to `Subtract`, `Multiplication`, and `Division`.

---

Note that `1 <= choice <= 4` almost certainly does not do what you might expect. This is parsed as `(1 <= choice) <= 4`, which results in either `(0) <= 4` or `(1) <= 4`, depending on the value of choice. This expression will always be true.

Use the expression `1 <= choice && choice <= 4`.

---

Aside: `void main()` is rarely correct - use `int main(void)`.